# Is it possible to reference to JSON data itself within a schema definition?

Tags: json, schema, jsonschema

Is it possible to define a JSON schema to check inner data integrity? So that mistakes like `"ba"` could be detected without further runtime checks.

Data JSON

```json
{
   "childNames": ["foo", "bar", "baz"],
   "children": [
      {
         "name": "foo"
      },
      {
         "name": "ba"
      }
   ]
}
```

JSON Schema

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema",
    "$id": "https://tbd.com/foo/bar",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
       "childNames": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": { "type": "string" }
       },
       "children": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "name": {
                "type": "string",
                "enum": { "$ref": "???" }
              }
            }
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using .Net, then you can do this with JsonSchema.Net and JsonSchema.Net.Data.

You'll need to use a custom vocabulary which defines the `data` keyword.

Your schema will need to change to:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://gregsdennis.github.io/json-everything/meta/data",
  "$id": "https://tbd.com/foo/bar",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
     "childNames": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": { "type": "string" }
     },
     "children": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "name": {
              "data": {
                "enum": "#/childNames"
              }
            }
          }
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Note the `data` keyword where your `???` was and the different meta-schema in the `$schema` keyword.

You can try it on https://json-everything.net/json-schema.

Information on how this works is [here](https://gregsdennis.github.io/json-everything/usage/vocabs-data.html).

If you're not using .Net, you may need to figure out how to support this vocabulary (or work with the maintainer of the library you're using to do so).

*Disclaimer: I'm the creator & maintainer of JsonSchema.Net and the other [json-everything](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything) libraries.*